# How to format a corrupted SD Card

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, sd-card

I was writing something to the SD card at one point and I disconnected.

Unfortunately I am unable to boot into Raspbian now as it will simply boot loop and when I tried to use the tools

- Gparted
- Fdisk/CFdisk
- SD Cardformatter
- Etcher
- Win32DiskImager

Or simply trying to install a fresh version of the OS, or a different Linux distro it would only return errors. Or show that it worked only to be unplugged and replugged showing the same thing as before (many attempts did not work and returned the card could not be written to)

The card is a 16GB Samsung Evo Micro SDHC card and this is the partitions shown when it is put into gparted:

[image]

This is my first time using the Pi 2, please explain what I may be missing or doing wrong.

Comment: You **DO NOT** need to format to install an image. You need to be more specific about **exactly** you are doing and list error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to format SD cards properly is to put them into a digital compact camera or DSLR and using the formatting option of the camera. If that still doesn't work, your card might have entered permanent read-only mode to protect the data. This is irreversible.

Comment: Strange use of the term "easiest" - but this doesn't change the fact that formatting is un-necessary and futile (the ONLY reason to format is to install NOOBS).

Answer (score 0):

I've frequently found corrupted SD cards are no longer usable or reliable. Bin it and start afresh with a new one.

Comment: It would be helpful if he/she posted _what exactly_ he/she is doing though, because the partitions _are_ showing up in gparted, which means there might still be hope...